# basic php create composer package

Tags: php, json, composer-php

i want to create a basic web app use with composer.json autoload like framework but i didn't.

this is my folder structure ( project name is minisafe )

```
-minisafe
|-app
|--models
|--controllers
|--views
|-bootload
|--app.php
|--autoload.php
|-public
|--index.php
|--.htaccess
|-vendor
|--atlas
|---hanik
|----src
|-----Application
|------Application.php
|----composer.json
|--composer
|---...
|-composer.json
|-composer.lock
```

> composer.json in root dir is below :

```
{
    "require": {
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
        }
    }
}
```

> Application.php is below:

```
<?php namespace Application;

class Application {
    function __construct()
    {
        echo 'asd';
    }
}
```

> composer.json in atlas/hanik folder is below:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.0.*"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Application\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

> app.php in bootload folder is below:

```
<?php

$app = new Application\Application(realpath(__DIR__.'/../'));
```

this is not working and got this error. please help me ...

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN58b.png)

Comment: Please can you click [edit] and add your error message as text, having to click through to an image just makes life harder for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include composer autoload file (in your index/app.php file):

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

And I don't see it in your vendor directory.

Comment: i added it in bootload/autoload.php like this : 

<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

and i add this php file in index.php

<?php

require __DIR__.'/../bootload/autoload.php';

$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootload/app.php';

but not working

Comment: the second composer.json which in the src folder is why we use it and It caught my attention is vendor autoload file has no Application folder required. is it caused the error ?

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it.

i create a folder called packages and transported to atlas folder in it and add composer.json psr-4 section

> "Package\":"packages\atlas\hanik\src\"

and use like :

> $app = new Hanik\Application\Application(realpath(**DIR**.'/../'));
>
> return $app;

thats all of it :) ... thanks to everybody